# How to relocate a heap allocated array's beginning?

Tags: c, heap-memory

So suppose I'm implementing a queue using malloc, etc. Is there an easy way to tell a malloced array to instead start at arr[1] after we dequeue, so that it remains the same size? or if there's not enough space to do so (nearby the heap allocated array's location), instead realloc. This seems like there's a faster way considering we are reusing the data.

At first I thought I could just do arr = &arr[1] or something similar, but I don't know how that would work with stuff like realloc, etc.

Comment: You could use independent pointer variables to point to the next element as well as the end of the array. If the next element is equal to the end of the array, reallocate. Or just use a plain index and the current size.

Comment: What do you mean "so that it remains the same size"?  And you have to pass a valid pointer (returned by `malloc` or friends) to `realloc` and `free`, so you'll need some way to get back to that original value.

Comment: And you need the original pointer when you call `free` or `realloc`. So `arr = &arr[1]` will not work, as you will then loose the original pointer.

Comment: `arr = &arr[1]` will cause a memory leak if you lose where the original arr started.  Also freeing the middle of a malloced block doesn't work.  You can't just free arr[-2] to arr[-1] (if arr[-1] works)

Comment: A queue is an abstract data structure.  If you implement it with an array then you don't typically resize the array per push/pop operation.  You might want to look into the circular buffer data type.

Comment: Normally, you treat the queue as a ring buffer.  You have a pair of indexes which wrap around.  If you need to grow the queue, you reallocate, but otherwise, you have a pair of indexes.  When they're equal, the queue is empty.  One records where the next entry should be put; the other indicates where an entry should be read from.  When an index reaches the end of the array, it wraps around to the start (zero) again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate memory with `malloc()` or `realloc()` you take on the obligation release it by passing that same pointer (value) to `free()` which you therefor must retain.  While `realloc()` may move where an allocation to a different address you have no control over that.  `mmap()` allows you to hint of where you want a device mapped into memory but it's only a hint.

You copy the data in the array down a slot with `memmove()`, or you could allocate a new array and copy data over.

You typically leave the array alone once allocated.  Then maintain either a pair of indices relative to `arr`, or a `head` and `tail` pointer to figure out where to `enqueue()` (tail) and `dequeue` (head).  It's relatively easy to treat the array as a circular buffer that wraps around so you retain the full capacity.